# Update mediaElement based on slider value

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, windows-store-apps

I have a `mediaElement` and a `slider`.
The slider's maximum value is video's duration in seconds (for example if the video is 2 minutes, the slider's value is 120).

I want to update the mediaElement.Position based on the slider's value but the problems is that I dont want to update the position until the user FINISHED manipulating the value.

so what I did is 2 functions:

```
private void DurationSlider_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SeekToMediaPosition();
}
```

this function applys if the user stopped manipulating the slider.

```
private void DurationSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
     SeekToMediaPosition();
}
```

this function applys if the user clicked on different value in the slider.

The problem is that they clash.
Manipulating the slider cause the value to be changed...

so What I did is added this function:

```
bool manipulating = false;
private void DurationSlider_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    manipulating = true;
}
```

and in the ValueChanged function I checked whether `manipulating = true` or not 
It solved half of the problem - it does not change the video position while manipulating (until I finish) but if I click on different position on the slider (without releasing the mouse) and continue manipulating the slider's value - it changes the video position to where I clicked on the slider and then changes again to where I ended the manipulation.

So whats wrong?
I want to change the video position **ONLY** when the user released the mouse.
I cant find event that fires what I want...

Comment: Have you tried `ManipulationCompleted`/`PointerPressed`/`PointerReleased` event of `Slider` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **PointerCaptureLost** Event  to determine the position after the user finished dragging the control.

```
<Slider PointerCaptureLost=="Slider_PointerCaptureLost"  
        Height="27" Margin="132,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
```

Then in code behind.

```
    private void Slider_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider s = sender as Slider;
        // Your code
        MessageBox.Show(s.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: 1. There's no such event in Windows Store app. 2. ManipulatingCompleted is the equivalent and therefore the problem remains the same.

Comment: Yes, it does fix the problem. I can drop the 3 functions and use only this one to achieve what I need. thank you.